# Fast extraction of information from large text files with python

Tags: python, performance, memory-management, text-files

I am trying to do a script that can search for specific keys in a document. the document can be very large sometimes for that I would like something that can be really fast and efficient as well as use the smallest amounts of memory possible.

this is my code

```
Keys=('key1','key2','key3','key4','key5',...,'keyN')
LKeys=list(Keys)

with open('test.txt', 'r') as inF:
   for (N,line) in enumerate(inF):
      if any(x in line for x in LKeys):
           for k in LKeys:
               if k in line:
                  print N,k,line
                  print inF.next().strip() 
                  # Depending of the key sometimes I need to print next N lines
                  #Or do something else with the line for example save the next element after the key in a dictionary or database 
                  LKeyword.remove(k)
inF.close()
```

the test.txt can look something like this.

```
sdjskjd key1 jdjdjjd : 4
sdjskjd key2 jdjdjjd: 3 hdhdhd:NaN 

sdjskjd key4 jdjdjjd:
dfdgdfdfdffddfdf2t3h
dfdfdfdfdf5dfd3fhth21
dfdfdfdgghhgdhhghjh
.
.
.
sdjskjd keyN jdjdjjd : 1213.5678 Inz:Joe
```

for example:

```
Author  Antoine de Saint-Exupéry
Original title  Le Petit Prince
Translator  (English editions)
Katherine Woods
T.V.F. Cuffe
Irene Testot-Ferry
Alan Wakeman
Richard Howard[1]
David Wilkinson
Illustrator Antoine de Saint-Exupéry
Cover artist    Antoine de Saint-Exupéry
Country France
Language    French
Publisher   Reynal & Hitchcock (U.S.)
Gallimard (France)[2]
Publication date
September 1943 (U.S.: English & French)
(France, French, 1945)[2][Note 1]
Preceded by Pilote de guerre (1942)
Followed by Lettre à un otage (1944)

Author  Jostein Gaarder
Original title  Sofies verden
Country Norway
Language    Norwegian
Genre   Philosophical novel
Publisher   Berkley Books, Farrar, Straus and Giroux (original hardcover), MacMillan (audio)
Publication date
1991
Published in English
1994
Media type  Print (hardcover & paperback) and audiobook (English, unabridged CD & download)
Pages   518 pp
ISBN    978-1-85799-291-5
ISBN 978-1-4272-0087-7
ISBN 978-1-4272-0086-0
OCLC    246845141
LC Class    MLCM 92/06829 (P)

Auteur  Gabriel García Márquez
Pays    Drapeau de la Colombie Colombie
Genre   Roman
Réalisme magique
Version originale
Langue  Espagnol
Titre   Cien años de soledad
Éditeur Editorial Sudamericana
Lieu de parution    Buenos Aires
Date de parution    1967
Version française
Traducteur  Claude et Carmen Durand
Éditeur Éditions du Seuil
Lieu de parution    Paris
Date de parution    1968
Couverture  Élizabeth Butterworth
Nombre de pages 437
ISBN    202023811X
```

I read that a simple iteration to access the lines sequentially sometimes is the less memory demanding way to search and match for large documents and can be sometimes faster than regex.

Some comments about my keys they usually appear in a sequential order in my document and if the key is found it would not appear again for that I remove it from the list, however, there are cases in which not all the keys appear in the document but if key2 was found and then key4 chances are that key3 is just not in the document. Also, the keys are immutable and appear as exact words in the document.

Is there a better, more efficient, clean way to structure the code?

Comment: you do not need to close InF if you use with open ...

Answer (score 1):

So the following code, instead of using a tuple or list for keys it's using a set. So that means if there are thousands of keys the lookup will still be in constant time. Whereas in a list it will have to iterate through the list if you do `key in ['key', ..., 'keyN']`

For each line we split the words on spaces so we can do a lookup in the keys. Then if the word exist we can print it. If you need to remove the key from keys you would have to shrink the split words and check again.

However, since the check of the key in a set happens in constant time you don't really have to remove the key for efficiency reasons.

This is more efficient considering there can only be so many words in a line. But there could be N keys.

```
keys = {'key1','key2','key3','key4','key5',...,'keyN'}

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for no, line in enumerate(f):
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if word in keys:
                print(no, line)
                # find out which word actually matched by repeatedly 
                # shrinking a copy of the list words. 
                # then you could remove the key from keys
```

Also, you don't need to close the file. The context manager (ie with) takes care of closing the file after it's been read through.

Comment: What if a keyword repeats more than ones but I just need the data from the first match? For example, if the keys are 
keys={'Author','Language','Version'} and I just need the information of the first book.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Give a better example in your question?

Answer (score 0):

## Searching for keywords in a text file

I made some adjustement to your code. I don't know if this is what you were looking for, but this works anyhow.

```
Keys = ('Cover', "Cuffe")


with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as inF:
    for (N, line) in enumerate(inF):
        if any(x in line.split() for x in Keys):
            for k in Keys:
                if k in line.split():
                    print("(line)", N,
                          "(key)", k,
                          "(result)", line)
```

The output (using the data in your example of txt file) is:

> (line) 4 (key) Cuffe (result) T.V.F. Cuffe
>
> (line) 10 (key) Cover (result) Cover artist    Antoine de
>   Saint-Exupéry

## Version for python 2.7

```
Keys = ('Cover', "Cuffe")

with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as inF:
    for (N, line) in enumerate(inF):
        if any(x in line.split() for x in Keys):
            for k in Keys:
                if k in line.split():
                    print "(line)", N,
                          "(key)", k,
                          "(result)", line
```